# How to change default annotation properties in ArcMap 10.4?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, annotation, arcgis-10.4

I am trying to figure out how to change the default properties of an annotation feature class in ArcMap 10.4. I see the "Text Symbol" box when I double-click on the "Default" category under my annotation feature class in the table of contents, but every option in it is greyed out.

Also, I cannot figure out how to make a new template for annotation either. I know how to do it with regular features in the Create Features window. Any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I would use ArcCatalog instead of ArcMap to change properties

1. Close all instances of ArcMap the are connected to the Anno.
2. Open ArcCatalog and connect to the Anno Feature Class
3. Then right click and go to properties.
4. Click on the Annotation Classes tab
5. Change your default values and click apply.

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried this but all the fields are still grayed out.